# GWT Fire ValueChangeEvent after a specific time

Tags: gwt, timer, textbox

I have an webapp with a large collection. So my user get a text box to filter the collection.
But every time the user put in one letter the filter action starts. This is very slow some times.

So I want only get the value change event when the user stop typing for one second.

I tried it this way:

```
  @Override
  public void onValueChange( ValueChangeEvent<String> event )
  {
    Timer t = new Timer()
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        addChangeHandler( new ChangeHandler()
        {
          @Override
          public void onChange( ChangeEvent event1 )
          {
            ValueChangeEvent.fire( TextBoxPSG.this, getValue() );
          }
        } );
      }
    };
    t.schedule( 15000 );
  }
```

But this doesn't work. 
Maybe someone has an Idea or the same problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use ValueChangeEvent. Use KeyUpEvent.

```
private static Timer timer = new Timer() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do you filter work;
    }
};

...
myTextBox.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
        if (timer.isRunning()) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
        timer.schedule(1000);
    }

});
```

Comment: That's help a lot but we won't implement this each time we need a filter. It would be nice to do this directliy in the text box. So only let the text box fire a changeEvent or something else after the time.

Comment: Then you will need to subclass a TextBox, basically moving the same code inside a TextBox. If you only need it in a few places, then my solution is a better option.

Comment: I found another nice solution. I write my own event. Then in the run method I fire this event. So everyone who is intrested to this event can get it.